# daemon threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

After reading: http://pymotw.com/2/threading/#daemon-vs-non-daemon-threads I expect following code to terminate after 2 seconds:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def a():
    i = 0
    while 1:
            print i
            i+=1



t = Thread(target=a)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.run()
sleep(2)
```

However, it keeps printing numbers forever. Am I missing something here? I am on win7. I get same behaviour from windows shell and idle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `t.start()`, not `t.run()`. The first one will spawn a new thread and call `run` itself from there. Calling run on your own causes you to execute the `a` function in your current thread.

Comment: Answer was much simpler than I thought :)